# How to format phone number with v-model on VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When the phone number is entered, I want it to appear in the input in the format (123) - 456 - 78 - 90. how can I do it?

```
<template>
<div v-for="about in abouts">
  <input type="text" v-model="about.phone">
  <input type="text" v-model="about.mail">
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return{
      abouts:[{phone:'',mail:''},{phone:'',mail:''}]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const q = (ph) => {
  const batches = [3, 3, 2, 2];
  const template = '({0}) - {1} - {2} - {3}';
  let index = 0, summator = 0;
  let data = template;
  batches.forEach(x => {
    const part = ph.substring(summator, x + summator);
    data = data.replace(`{${index}}`, part);
    index++;
    summator += x;
  });
  return data;
}
```

and then include it in your data:

```
abouts:[{phone:q('1234567890'),mail:''},{phone:'',mail:q('')}]
```

simple way, working. You can add trimming if phone number smaller than 10 digits

Comment: If you could explain a little about the code, or just comments in between the lines to make it more understandable.

Comment: How do i run this with v-model?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. If you have the same problem you can use vue-mask package.

Comment: Can you add more details to your answer? What is the package doing? How to use it? This will improve your answers quality and help others with same or similar problem